# RadiusNetwork AltBeacon leaking ServiceConnection

Tags: android, memory-leaks, altbeacon

**"MainActivity has leaked ServiceConnection org.altbeacon.beacon.BeaconManager that was originally bound here"** - this is the problem, I'm facing. I'm using AltBeacon from a class in a library. The class is getting passed a Context element at instantiation. The class implements BeaconConsumer and the overrides are acting like shown below:

```
@Override
public Context getApplicationContext() {
    return mContext.getApplicationContext();
}
@Override
public boolean bindService(Intent intent, ServiceConnection connection, int mode) {
    return mContext.bindService(intent, connection, mode);
}

@Override
public void unbindService(ServiceConnection connection) {
    mContext.unbindService(connection);
}
@Override
public void onBeaconServiceConnect() {
         // do things
}
```

The bindService works, but because there is no onDestroy in the library (and finalize() is never called either), unbindService will never be called. This leads to the leak mentioned above.

How can I recover from that? I don't want to expose a special cleanup() function, the library shall be able to detect the shutdown moment and should cleanup internally. Is that possible?

Any pointer welcome.
Regards

Answer (score 0):

OK, added a cleanup function.
Solved

Comment: Even though user3534326's "answer" was invalid as an answer, it is still valid as a comment. Could you elaborate on how you solved your Problem (and then ideally mark this answer as accepted)? Thank you very much!

Comment: Well, commenting after month's is not easy, the more I don't see why you are calling user3534326's "answer". Maybe it is deleted. I remember to have had an extra cleanup function in my library, which explicitly made the "unbind", but that was just for a little while. The current solution does make the binding/unbinding at start/stop scan, so this is symmetrical. I also think, that this problem has been addressed by the Beacon library guys in later versions, but I'm not sure

Comment: Thank you for your time. I am indeed talking about a (now deleted) "answer" that only contained something like "how did you solve it". I am certain that it muss be difficult to recall your solution. So thanks for trying! Lets hope the user got some help. The next time you find a solution for your question, it would be awesome if you would share the details for future vision like him. Anyway, thanks again for commenting on this old case

Comment: Hi, can i know the cleanup function, i am facing the same issue.

Comment: @pallavi: I don't have that any longer. See my comment from Nov 11th 15 how I did solve that